# What the limitations of Listen server?

Tags: networking, game-engine, ping

Let's say that I have a game server located in my country which is hosted by my ISP. For example, I pinged their game server and I got 10 ms ping, and let's say the game features the ability to host the game by your machine (listen server) instead.

So let's say that my friend is going to be hosting that game and I'm going to join him and rely on his connection to me, and suppose he lives just next to my home and we have the same ISP. Is it possible that I'm going to get ping times of around 10 ms just like dedicated server or will be higher? If yes, is it because the limitations of the machine itself, or what could be the cause?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A listen server would actually have the ping timing being dependent upon the machine hosting the game and the game latency would eventually depend on your machine and your connection.

Whereas if you have a dedicated server, the ping timing would not be affected by your connection overload or any sort of such network problems.

Also the ping timing depends on the distance but in a particular residential area every ping would be routed through a majorly one router and hence the ping timings would not be different.

As for the model, I guess you should go for dedicated server because it provides better performance. For more information you could check out the following link:

http://www.gameskinny.com/pqdqx/dedicated-servers-vs-peer-to-peer-connections

Comment: Oh i see. Well is it possible to have the lowest ping time on a local host machine that functions normally and get anything under 10ms? assuming they live closer to each other? my friend tells me that local hosting can't handle any ping under 30ms due to slow/weak processing when compared to dedicated servers. is that true?

Comment: The ping latency timings depend on the kind of network you are on and the number of devices between the source and the destination. Like for a local area network, if you have a lan network via copper cables, then you could easily say that the timings would not be less than 30ms.

Comment: Also could you let me know what more information is required in order to accept this as an answer?

Comment: Well let me rephrase my question once again regarding listen server: lets say, i have a game server located in my country which is hired by my ISP. and for example i pinged their game server and i got 10ms ping. and lets say the game features the ability to host the game by your machine(Listen server) instead. So let's say that my friend is going to be hosting that game and i'm going to join him and rely on his connection to me. and let's say he lives just next to my home and we have the same ISP. then, is it possible that i'm going to get ping times of around 10ms just like dedicated server?

Comment: Please add this to the original question, so that it would benefit other users also. Meanwhile I will try to search a suitable reply